# Unable to inject service in angular js

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm constantly failing to inject the `$log` service in a minify save way into a controller class of a component.

To check the injection is save, I added `ng-strict-di` to my app. This in terms causes an `SearchResultController is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode` which is fine, since I'm relying on implicit injection right now.

So I added an explicit injection to my component implementation:

```
import htmlTemplate from './searchInput.html';

class SearchInputController {

    constructor($log) {
        this._log = $log;
        this.searchText = 'Text to search for';
    }

    handleUpdate() {
        this.onChange({value: this.searchText});
    }

    doubleMe(i) {
        this._log.debug('SearchInputController.doubleMe: i='+i);
        return i+i;
    }
}

SearchInputController.$inject = ['$log'];

let searchInputComponent = {

  template: htmlTemplate,
    controller: SearchInputController,
    bindings: {
        onChange: '&'
    }

};

export default searchInputComponent;
```

This has no effect the error message is still complaining about the missing injection.

I also tried ng-annotate-loader and ng-annotate-webpack-plugin. And also tried the `/*@ngInject*/` and `'ngInject';` type annotations. All of this has no effect.

Any ideas how to get the dependency injection working?

Comment: You say the error message complains about `SearchResultController`, but you posted us the source for `SearchInputController`.

Comment: Thanks! I just missed that. Saved my day :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your annotation appears to be correct for `SearchInputController`, but the error message is complaining about a different controller `SearchResultController`. I suggest you need to annotate that one also.

Use https://babeljs.io/repl/ to check how ES6 compiles down to ES5. This can be useful when trying to trace errors in annotation. Using `ng-annotate` in some form should also work when you annotate the correct controller.